# Terminator Haircut Change

Tags: realism, terminator-series, the-terminator

Is there a reason why Terminator haircut changes after he crashes into the wall? Is there a deleted scene by any chance that was cut out as one can see that haircut of terminator changes.
This is in the pub - hair is long.
   [image]
Then after the car crash hair suddenly becomes short.
[image]

Comment: That's awesome!! XD I heard that in Wizard of Oz, Dorothy's hair changes length while she's singing "Over the Rainbow". Both of them were probably caused by the same disregard for continuity. Or, with Terminator, it could be that they shot the pub scene last, and Arnold's hair had grown out since the start of the shoot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

His hair is partly burned off in an explosion.

As you can (just about) see when he's chasing down Kyle and Sarah after the shootout in [Tech Noir](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Noir), his hair is long and flowing:

[image: Image of The Terminator in the alley]

Then when Sarah and Kyle get to their car, Kyle shoots at the petrol tank of a car in front of him and blows it up, then The Terminator jumps through the flames and catches fire:

[image: Image of a burning Terminator jumping]

In the very next shot, you can see he has shorter hair and there's smoke coming off him:

[image: Image of a burned Terminator]

In the next scene after Kyle and Sarah have escaped, The Terminator assaults a cop to steal his car and The Terminator's hair is still smouldering:

[image: Image of The Terminator assaulting a cop]

So as you can see, it's absolutely intentional.

Comment: He must have cleaned it up afterwards, probably in his motel room, because burnt hair does not come out so Lorel perfect.

Comment: @cde Possibly right after pulling out the damaged eye and fixing the misfiring servos in his arm ;-)

Comment: You see the terminator checking his newly trimmed hair during the eye surgery scene.